# How to force the compiler to show implicit constructors

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang

There's "-E" option for gcc or clang to run preprocessor and show how all macros are expanded, and I need something like this for implicitly generated methods.

Is there a way to force gcc or clang to print implicitly created and deleted constructors/destructors/assignment operators for each class?

Comment: Not exactly what you want, but take a look at https://cppinsights.io

Comment: @NickyC thanks, that's handy. However not applicable to my case as I'm working with a large codebase.

Answer (score 3):

You may use the template type traits as a workaround to extract such information from certain types. This can not distinguish whether something was explicitely deleted or implicitely, but you know for sure if you didn't do it explicitely, like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct A { 
    A(const A&) = delete;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_trivially_default_constructible_v<A> << '\n';
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_copy_assignable_v<A> << '\n';
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_trivially_move_constructible_v<A> << '\n';
}
```

will yield `false, true, false`, i.e. for example the trivial default constructor is implicitely deleted when the copy constructor got explicitely deleted.

Edit: Here is an example that goes through a class hierarchy and finds the base class that violates a certain trait:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>

struct A {
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&&) noexcept { }
};

struct B : A {
    using base_type = A;
    B(B&& b) : A(std::move(b)) { }
};

struct C : B {
    using base_type = B;
};

struct D : C {
    using base_type = C;
};

template <typename T, bool = std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<typename T::base_type>>
struct check { };

template <typename T>
struct check<T, false> : check<typename T::base_type> { };

template <typename T>
struct check<T, true> {
    using result_t = T;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << typeid(check<D>::result_t).name() << '\n';
}
```

From there on, you may get the idea to enhance and generalize it on your own.

Comment: I went to a training that recommended setting such compile-time checks *explicitly* under class definitions, sort of like "basic unit-tests", but really as contract validators regarding class interface.

Comment: @Jodocus this is exactly what I'm currently doing (like `static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible)`). However this is rather manual and per-class only. It becomes quite cumbersome to narrow down the problematic parent class (say with deleted move-constructor) in the large hierarchy of classes that I'm currently working with, and I would like to use grep/sed/etc.

Comment: @DevNull I fear you have to build this on your own. You can easily produce output that you can use together with e.g. grep. For the class hierarchies: you may write a class template that recursively goes through the class hierarchy tree using some basic template metaprogramming.

Comment: @Jodocus could you please point me to an example of some basic template metaprogramming for traversing class hierarchies of parent classes and their members?

Comment: @DevNull Why would you want to traverse class members? This is currently not really possible with C++. From what I read from your comments, you may also have a look into C++ concepts (though not part of the standard yet).

Comment: @Jodocus given a class `A` that is not `std::is_nothrow_move_constructible`, I want to recursively find such parent classes or members of `A` that actually disable 'noexcept move constructor' and to see why they disable it.

Comment: @DevNull See the Edit.